# WCF service stop working 10054 WSAECONNRESET Connection reset by peer

Tags: c#, wcf

I have two WCF Services running in a Windows Forms application (C# / .NET 4) in my Computer (Windows 8):

First service: https://localhost:9002

Second service: https://local_192-168-1-104.desktop.Company.com:9003

The first service is accessed locally, the second is accessed by others computers in local network. The host: local_192-168-1-104.desktop.Company.com is resolved by DNS to ip: 192.168.1.104, this is my local network ip address.

Both services use https, the first use a SelfSigned Certificate, the second, a certificate for: desktop.Company.com

**Problem**: After some time of inactivity, the second service stop working.

No exception is logged and the events Faulted(), UnknownMessageReceived(), Closing() or Closed() of WebServiceHost is not executed.

If I close the application and start this again, the problem continues. In this error situation, the State property of WebServiceHost is "Opened", but the service does not respond.

If I stop the service, reconfigure the service (topic: Configure Certificate Service 2), and start this again, the problem stop for a while.

I test the wcf service using this:

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += webClient_DownloadDataCompleted;
    webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("https://local_192-168-1-104.desktop.Company.com:9003/Message/Test"));
}
```

And I recived this exception:

**The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.**

```
>> INNER EXCEPTION:
Message: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Type: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
Source: System
TargetSite: Int32 EndReceive(System.IAsyncResult)
ErrorCode: 10054
StackTrace:
---------------------------
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
---------------------------
```

The Windows Error Code **10054** is:

**Connection reset by peer.**

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. This
>   normally results if the peer application on the remote host is
>   suddenly stopped, the host is rebooted, the host or remote network
>   interface is disabled, or the remote host uses a hard close (see
>   setsockopt for more information on the SO_LINGER option on the remote
>   socket). This error may also result if a connection was broken due to
>   keep-alive activity detecting a failure while one or more operations
>   are in progress. Operations that were in progress fail with
>   WSAENETRESET. Subsequent operations fail with WSAECONNRESET.

I try to disable the Keep Alive, but the problem continues.

Below more details:

**Configure Certificate Service 1**

```
netsh http delete urlacl url=https://+:9002/
netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:9002
netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:9002/ user=Everyone
makecert -sk RootCA -sky signature -pe -n CN=localhost -r -sr LocalMachine -ss Root certificate\CustomCertificate_MyCA.cer
makecert -sk server -sky exchange -pe -n CN=localhost -ir LocalMachine -is Root -ic certificate\CustomCertificate_MyCA.cer -sr LocalMachine -ss My certificate\CustomCertificate.cer
(install certificate in CertificateStore)
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:9002 certhash=F3F40BF81AF0.... appid={00a1d32c-68bd-4693-a872-...}
```

**Start service 1**

```
var mainServiceHost = new Company.Library.WCF.JSONServiceHost("localhost", 9002, true);
mainServiceHost.Start(typeof(Service.Message), typeof(Service.IMessage), false);
```

**Configure Certificate Service 2**

```
netsh http delete urlacl url=https://+:9002/
netsh http delete sslcert ipport=192.168.1.146:9003
netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:9003/ user=Everyone
(install certificate in CertificateStore)
netsh http add sslcert ipport=192.168.1.146:9003 certhash=1C36C9C... appid={00a1d32c-68bd-4693-a872-1473...}
```

**Start service 2**

```
var localServerServiceHost = new Company.Library.WCF.JSONServiceHost("local_192-168-1-104.desktop.Company.com", 9003, true);
localServerServiceHost.Start(typeof(Service.Message), typeof(Service.IMessage), false);
```

**JSONServiceHost Class**

```
public void Start(Type serviceType, Type implementedContract, bool keepAliveEnabled)
{
    EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(Url);

    CustomServiceBehavior serviceBehavior = new CustomServiceBehavior();
    svcWebHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceBehavior);

    BindingElementCollection bindingElements;

    WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport);

    bindingElements = binding.CreateBindingElements();
    if (bindingElements != null)
    {
        var transport = bindingElements.Find<HttpsTransportBindingElement>();
        if (transport != null)
            transport.KeepAliveEnabled = keepAliveEnabled;
    }

    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue;
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = int.MaxValue;
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = int.MaxValue;
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = int.MaxValue;
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue;
    binding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
    binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue;
    binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;

    binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

    ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint = svcWebHost.AddServiceEndpoint(implementedContract, binding, endpoint.Uri);

    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
    svcWebHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

    ServiceDebugBehavior sdb = svcWebHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
    if (sdb != null)
        sdb.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;

    foreach (var operation in serviceEndpoint.Contract.Operations)
        operation.Behaviors.Add(new CustomOperationBehavior());

    svcWebHost.Open();
}
```

**Aditional Configurations executed when Application Start**

```
private static void ConfigureGlobalServiceParameters()
{
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = false;
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = int.MaxValue;
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.DnsRefreshTimeout = -1;
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 20 * 1000;
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.MaxServicePoints = 10;
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate { return true; });
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SetTcpKeepAlive(false, 0, 0);
}
```

**CustomEndpointBehavior**

```
public class CustomEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        var customInspector = new CustomDispatchMessageInspector();
        endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(customInspector);
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }
}
```

**CustomOperationBehavior**

```
public class CustomOperationBehavior : IOperationBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientOperation clientOperation)
    {   
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {
    }

    public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription)
    {
    }
}
```

**CustomServiceBehavior**

```
public class CustomServiceBehavior : IServiceBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        CustomEndpointBehavior endpointBehavior = new CustomEndpointBehavior();
        foreach (var endpoint in serviceDescription.Endpoints)
            endpoint.Behaviors.Add(endpointBehavior);
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Additional Information: I have created a Thread testing the service every 5 minutes, using this the problem never happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I come back to this problem, and finally found a solution.

It isn't a problem of WCF, the WCF stop working because the association of certificate to windows port is not working.

**The problem:**

1. You have a certificate (not a Self Signed Certificate);
2. You associate this certificate to a windows port using the command: "netsh http add sslcert" and use this in a WCF or other service;
3. After a reboot, or a long time of system Idle, this stop working;

**Consequences:**

After a windows reboot the service stop working in this port, and the behavior described bellow occur:

1. If you try to execute a Http request to url, you receive this error:
   The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
2. If you try to associate the certificate to port again, using this command:

command: `netsh http add sslcert ipport=192.168.1.146:9003 certhash=1C36.. appid={00a1..}`

You receive this error:

> SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 1312
>   A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.

3. If you try to export the certificate, using this:

command: `certutil -exportPFX -p "[password]" My [cert_SerialNumber] "c:\temp\desktop.pfx" NoChain`

You receive this error:

> Private key is NOT exportable
>   Encryption test passed
>   CertUtil: -exportPFX command FAILED: 0x8009000b (-2146893813 NTE_BAD_KEY_STATE)
>   CertUtil: Key not valid for use in specified state.

**How to reproduce all the configuration process:**

1. Get certificate from .pfx:

code: `X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certPath, password);`

2. Add certificate certificate to CertificateStore (StoreName: "MY", StoreLocation: LocalMachine):

   X509Store store = new X509Store(storeName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
   store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
   store.Add(certificate);
   store.Close();
3. Attach certificate to port:

command: `netsh http add sslcert ipport=192.168.1.146:9003 certhash=1C36C... appid={00a..} clientcertnegotiation=enable`

4. Configure windows firewall to allow access to port:

(I do this, because I'm accessing the WCF from another computer in local network)

**How to solve the problem manually:**

In this article:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx

There are this solution:

> I think by moving the self signed cert from Personal to Trusted Root
>   CA directory causes a problem that SSL stops working after developers
>   reboot their machines. (Don't know how it happens, but it does happen
>   consistently.) I finally get around this issue by export and re-import
>   the self-signed cert into the trusted root directory (instead of
>   simply drag it over). Now my self-signed cert is considered and I
>   don't need to REINSTALL/REPAIR IIS Express every time I reboot the
>   machine.

Miraculously, you don't need to export the certificate from Personal Certificate Store, and import the certificate in Root. You just need manually export the certificate before the windows reboot, and the problem don't happen after the windows reboot.

**How to solve the problem using command line:**

After the process of configuration, and before the first windows reboot, execute this:

1. Import the certificate to "Personal" certificate Store:

command: `certutil -f -p "[password]" -importpfx My "c:\temp\cert.pfx"`

2. Export the certificate using this:

command: `certutil -exportPFX -p "[password]" My [certificate_Serial_Number] "c:\temp\cert2.pfx" NoChain`

**Valuable information:**

1. List certificates installed in Windows Local Machine Certification Store:

   - Start / Run: mmc.exe
   - File / Add/Remove Snap-in…
   - Under Available snap-ins, select "Certificates", then "Local Machine" and press Add.
2. List certificates associated to port using the command "netsh http add sslcert"

command: `certutil -store "My"`

3. To remove a association of certificate to port:

command: `netsh http delete sslcert ipport=192.168.1.104:9003`

4. certutil reference:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732443.aspx

5. netsh reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc307220(v=vs.85).aspx